# Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10 and Windows 8.1 in a lenovo Y480

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I'm new to the Linux environment. I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 in a Lenovo Y480 with Windows 8.1, but when the installer asked me what do I want to do, the option to keep both the OS does not appear. How can I install Ubuntu on this laptop?

Comment: is there any option like `something else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical Ubuntu installation alongside Windows will go as follows:

- Insert Ubuntu installation disk (LiveDVD or LiveUSB) in the system and boot from it.
- Choose Install Ubuntu when asked to either try or install it.
- Select language
- When Preparing to Install window appears, it will present you with following options

  - **Install Ubuntu alongside your other systems** (eg alongside Windows). Select this option in your case.
  - Erase disk and install Ubuntu (Install Ubuntu over your entire hard drive).
  - Something else (use manual options for installations, like partitioning hard drive and then install).

Here is the [graphical step-by-step installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#continueinstall) for dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. A more detailed Wiki is available [here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aAll#Dual-Booting_Windows_and_Ubuntu).